# Delete documents from MongoDB collection after some time

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am looking for a way to delete all documents after a certain time for example after 30 days.

I have tried the TTL index, which is working fine in the case when the saving document contains a date field. However, in my case, the saved document doesn't contain any date field. I just want to delete all the documents right after 30 days for example.

For example, in the case of Cosmos db, there is a partition level setting that allows us to specify expire date for all documents in that partition, regardless if there is any expiration field in the document itself.

In case of Cosmos db, we have below three modes of TTL, I am finding equivalent of these modes in MongoDB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSyMI.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How can the database know when 30 days passed by, if you have no date field? Other solution would be to create on collection per day and drop outdated collections by daily job.

Comment: I am looking for setting on collection level

Comment: When you insert a new document, then a `_id` field is created automatically, see [_id](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). It contains the insert time, however *the _id field does not support TTL indexes*, see [Restrictions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#restrictions) But you can delete documents manually based on time of `_id`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - For Cosmos DB's MongoDB API (which I am guessing the OP is using, as they brought up Cosmos DB's SQL API), there is no need for an explicit date field to create a ttl-based index. It uses the underlying `_ts` property, and deletes after the specified time period elapses since last create/modify time. It has nothing to do with `_id`.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking about native MongoDB, or Cosmos DB's MongoDB API? I am guessing the latter since you brought up Cosmos DB in your question, but maybe I'm making a bad assumption? Please edit your question (and tags) to be specific.

Comment: I am talking about native MongoDB. 
I mentioned Cosmos DB because I found TTL against the collection level in the Cosmos DB.